# Show that $\| T^{\ast}T \| = \| T \|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Suppose that $T$ is any bounded operator. I want to show that $\| T^{\ast} T \| = \| T \|^2$. Can you please check my proof.

Consider that $\| T \|^2 = \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1} \| Tx \|^2 = \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1} \left| \langle x, T^{\ast}Tx \rangle \right| \leq \| T^{\ast}T \|$ and $\| T^{\ast} T \| = \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1} \| T^{\ast}Tx\| = \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1} \left| \langle x, T^2 x \rangle \right| \leq \| T \|^2$.

Comment: Seems correct $\,$

Comment: How do you get $\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|T^*Tx\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}|\langle x,T^2x\rangle|$?

Comment: @Aweygan How would I justify this? I used the reasoning from the other direction.

Comment: @user3359 I don't know how, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @Aweygan How would I then show that $\| T^{\ast} T \| \leq \| T \|^2$?

Comment: Show that $\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|\leq\|T^*\|\|T\|$, then apply the same reasoning for $T^*$ in place of $T$.

Answer (score -1):

You make a similar gap in both inequalities you are trying to show.  Specifically, you claim that $\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|\left< x, Ax\right>| \leq \|A\|$. This claim requires justification.

Comment: What would the intermediary step be?

Comment: I don't know why this is a big deal, $\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|\left< x, Ax\right>| \leq\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|A\|\|x\|^2=\|A\|$